# ContentResolver - how to get get random access / seekable representation of the resource which maps to file

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

How do I access ContentResolver content as a file? There's a simple way to open underlying file-based content as an InputStream, but it's not possible to seek on InputStream. There's RandomAccessFile, but either File or file name is needed to create instances.

Content I'm trying to read is mapped to file (email attachment).

Comment: Can you use `InputStream.skip()`?

Comment: I'd like to move to beginning of file too

Comment: skip() has big penalty cost, as it usually skips by reading the data. There seems to be no good solution to seek within such stream.